# Github pages with custom sub-domain doesn't redirect to sub-domain

Tags: redirect, dns, github-pages

I have a personal blog site hosted on github pages. I've updated the repository settings and DNS settings according to [offical document](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-subdomain/). Unfortunately redirection doesn't work properly, access to original github URL is not forwarded to my sub-domain but top domain name. What's going wrong?

My github page repository is `skyscribe.github.io` and in the project setting, I've set the custom domain as `www.skyscribe.me`; now when I navigate to `skyscribe.github.io`, it just redirects to `skyscribe.me` than `www.skyscribe.me`.

**EDIT**: I have setup my CNAME in DNS resolver properly.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a [CNAME](https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) file.

Also I just checked, it seems to be redirecting to `www.skyscribe.me`